# Integer array indexing python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

print(a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0]])  # Prints "[1 4 5]"

print(a[[0, 0], [1, 1]])  # Prints "[2 2]"
```

I don't understand why it results `[1 4 5]` and `[2 2]`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have no expectation about that. I wonder why it results so

Answer (score 4):

Because you're slicing the array with indexes

`a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0]]` is equivalent to

```python
a[0, 0]  # 1
a[1, 1]  # 4
a[2, 0]  # 5
```

whereas `a[[0, 0], [1, 1]]` is equivalent to twice `a[0, 1]`

More about Numpy indexing [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: is there a way to get a C or even fortran like array in python? The lists and othe rdata structure s seem very confusing especially combined with the strange scoping rules it seems to apply

Comment: Hi @user50619. Probably your question fits another thread better. Short answer is that numpy deals with C-like arrays under the hood, and you can orient the array C-like or Fortran-like. Please visit [the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/internals.html) for further details

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as 2d-array access. When you initialize a you get your 2d array in the form:

```
[ 1  2 ]
[ 3  4 ]
[ 5  6 ]
```

Numpy indexing when given a 2d array works as follows: you input a list of the row indexes, then a list of the column indexes. Semantically your first index retrieval statement is saying "from row 0 retrieve element 0, from row 1 retrieve element 1, and from row 2 retrieve element 0" which corresponds to `[1 4 5]`. You can then figure out why you get [2 2] for the second statement.

You can read more about this advanced indexing here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing